# Proof: Product of Expectation of two independent random variables!

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Consider two independent Random variables A, and B, now I know that,
**E[A+B] = E[A] + E[B]**, **E[AB] = E[A] * E[B]**.

I am looking for a prove of these properties, I am successful in proving the first one, but I am unable to prove the 2nd property.

Can anyone throw some guideline, or a starting point for the second proof?

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the finite case with $E[A]=\sum_j p_j a_j$ (where $p_j=P(A=a_j)$) and $E[B]=\sum_k q_k b_k$ (where $q_k=P(B=b_k)$), we have
$$ E[AB]=\sum_{j,k} p_jq_k a_jb_k=\sum_j p_ja_j\cdot\sum_kq_kb_k=E[A]E[B]$$
(where by independence $p_jq_k=P(A=a_j)P(B=b_k)=P(A=a_j,B=b_k)$).