# Orthogonality of random vectors and the inner product

Tags: statistics, complex-numbers, vectors

[An acclaimed answer to the question `What does orthogonal mean in statistics?`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16315/67822) is beautifully stripped down to

$$\mathbb E[\mathbf {XY^*}]=0$$

I am not familiar with the operations involved, not just because of the inclusion of complex numbers, but most important, because I don't see the use of the **inner product** in this context. [In this post](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Spaces.html#Inner_Product):

> The vector space $\mathscr L_2$ of real-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbb P)$ (modulo equivalence of course) with finite
>   second moment is special, because it's the only one in which the norm
>   corresponds to an inner product. If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables
>   in $\mathscr L_2$, we define the inner product of $X$ and $Y$ by
>
> $⟨X,Y⟩=\mathbb E[XY]$

---

In relations to the comments below I find this quote on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Examples):

> For real random variables $X$ and $Y$, the expected value of their
>   product $\displaystyle \langle X,Y\rangle :=\operatorname {E} (XY)$ is
>   an inner product. This definition of expectation as inner product can
>   be extended to random vectors as well.

---

The actual hurdle:

Now, this inner product is not the dot product of two vectors, is it? If the idea is to multiply the elements of two random vectors $X$ and $Y$ and then perform the inner product of this multiplication vector with itself, we'd be getting $[XY]^2$ - more like a norm... I think there is more to inner product, included in the quotes I pasted above, and requiring knowledge of abstract algebra. This probably includes the concept of the vector space $\mathscr L_2$.

---

What I got so far:

Since,

\begin{align}
Cov[X,Y]=&E[(X−E[X])\cdot(Y−E[Y])]\\
&=E[X\cdot Y]−E[X\cdot E[Y]]−E[E[X]\cdot Y]+E[E[X]\cdot E[Y]]\\
&=E[X\cdot Y]−E[X]\cdot E[Y]
\end{align}
​
and consequently,

$$E[XY]=Cov[X,Y]+E[X]\cdot E[Y],$$

real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ are **uncorrelated** (different from independent) if and only if the centered variables $X-E(X)$ and $Y-E(Y)$ are **orthogonal**: $E[XY]=0.$

Comment: Observe that $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, ie, $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$.

Comment: I guess perhaps your greatest doubt lies with what an inner product is? Or proving that this operation defines indeed an inner product in that vector space?

Comment: $XY$ is not dot procut; it's the conventional product of two numbers. The dot product (or inner product, rather) is the expectation of $XY$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I structured the OP a bit better, emphasizing the fact that, in this context, the inner product sounds more like a norm or measure, rather than a test of orthogonality, but evidently something is not falling in place...

Comment: I found a partial answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1468434/152225).

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what your question is.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri You multiply for example 1000 random draws from a normal distribution to generate $X$, and do the same for $Y$. Now you multiply the results, giving you a vector $XY$. Then, what is the next step to get the inner product? $[XY]^T[XY]$? That will never be zero.

Comment: I think I understand now. The proble is you're thinking $X$ and $Y$ are random **vectors** when the pieces of text you're referring to say $X$ and $Y$ are random **variables** that take on real values (ie, they're numbers).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Sorry to bother you with this, but I think I'm close to getting what the problem is - when we talk about "inner product" in this setting, there are no vectors involved. So in the case of two independent r.v.'s we could be looking at the "inner product" looking something like this: $E[XY]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xyf_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy$?

Comment: Yes, the formula you posted *is* the inner product (as was defined) between $X$ and $Y$. Notice that $X$ and $Y$ *are* indeed vectors in the space $\mathscr L_2$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thank you very much. That was complete intuition on my part. This post has shown me that there is much more to "inner product" than the simple idea of dot product of two vectors as in [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html). It would be great if you could sketch out the overall picture in a formal answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An inner product is a structure in a vector space that introduces 'geometry', specifically the notion of angles, to the space. We have the following 'chain' of structures.

First, a **vector space** is a set in which we're allowed to add two of its elements (and the result is still in the set!). It has all nice usual properties of addition, like commutativity or a neutral element, the zero vector. A vector space also allows it to multiply its elements by a number (usually a real or complex number), and multiplication also works with addition as usual.

Then, we can introduce a **norm** into our space. This is a way of measuring vectors, of assigning them a length if you will. The usual norm for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the euclidean norm $\sqrt{\sum_i {x_i}^2}\,$, but there are plenty of other ways to measure length. For instance, sometimes it's better to use the [taxicab (or Manhattan) distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Finally, we get into **inner products**. This is a way of introducing geometry to our space. An inner product assigns to each pair $u,v$ of vectors a number (real or complex) $\langle u,v\rangle$, and it has some fundamental properties:

\begin{align}
&\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}&\text{(where $\,\overline{\dot{}}\,$ is complex conjugation)}\\
&\langle u,u\rangle \geq 0\\
&\langle u,u\rangle = 0 \Leftrightarrow u=0\\
&\langle t+u,v\rangle=\langle t,v\rangle+\langle u,v\rangle\\
&\langle \alpha \cdot u,v\rangle=\alpha \cdot \langle u,v\rangle &\text{(where $\alpha$ is a scalar)}
\end{align}

You are free to check that the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies these properties. That said, like with the norm, there are many other ways to define an inner product, and as long as it satisfies these properties, it is a valid definition.

Moreover, an inner product $\langle \dot{},\dot{}\rangle$ on a vector space **induces** a norm $\lVert \dot{} \rVert$ via

$$\lVert u \rVert = \sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}$$

Notice that the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ *is* the one obtained from its usual inner product!

Now, you may look at all this and ask 'But what does this have to do with geometry or angles?' The inner product is used to **define** the angle between vectors, in a manner similar to the one we use for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$$\cos(u,v)=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\lVert u \rVert \cdot \lVert v \rVert}$$

Like I said before, an inner product *introduces* geometry into a space, even if it may not be 'naturally' geometric to our own euclidean eyes (or minds -- many of these spaces are abstract). In fact, these structures are abstractions and generalizations of what we investigated about $\mathbb{R}^n$.

With this in mind, the pieces of text in your question refer to the **definition** of an inner product in the vector space $\mathscr L_2$, whose elements (or **vectors**) are random variables *that take on real values*. In particular, they do not take on 'lists' of numbers; they are each a single, real number.

It might be a good if somewhat easy exercise to check the properties of inner products, listed above. Hope this has helped!

Comment: Excellent road map to explore these topics in depth. Thank you. Is there a name for $\mathscr L_2$?

Comment: Not that I know of. I am not too versed in statistics or probability.